# SELECT QUERY IN MYSQL CALCULATING No. Of Hours between two datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to find the number of hours til now from `creationtime` and assigning color based on the job type and number of hours. `TIMEDIFF` in MySQL can be used to find the number of hours but then I am unable to use `IF` for giving color.

For a particular job type if it's created and not completed in two hours then it is showed in red, else for other job types and 18 hours red color.

Please correct me if I am going wrong in my approach and syntax.

```
SELECT jobid,   creationtime, jobstatus, 
       jobtype, store_id,
       IF( ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, creationtime, NOW() ) > 2 ) &&
           jobstatus NOT IN( 'complete', 'aborted' )          && 
           jobtype IN( 'AddItem', 'ReviseItem', 'EndItem', 'SoldReport', 
                       'ReviseFixedPriceItem',  'AddFixedPriceItem',
                       'EndFixedPriceItem'
                   ),
         'red',
         IF( ( TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, creationtime, NOW() ) > 18 ) &&
             jobstatus NOT IN( 'complete', 'aborted' )           &&
             jobtype = 'ActiveInventoryReport',
           'red',
           'white'
         )
       ) AS jobstatus_color
  FROM ebay.lms_jobs
  ORDER BY jobtype
```

Comment: what error you getting pate here

Comment: its not showing correct result..no error query runs perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```sql
jobtype = 'AddItem' || 'ReviseItem' || 'EndItem' ||
          'SoldReport' || 'ReviseFixedPriceItem' ||
          'AddFixedPriceItem' || 'EndFixedPriceItem'
```

This doesn't mean what you think it means. This is equivalent to:

```sql
( jobtype = 'AddItem' ) || TRUE || TRUE || TRUE || ...
```

...because in a boolean operation a string like `'ReviseItem'` is a true type.

In your code you're actually only comparing `jobtype` to `'AddItem'`. Then you're taking the result of that (which will be `TRUE` or `FALSE`) and doing a boolean *OR* (`||`) of it against `'ReviseItem'`, e.g. `FALSE || 'ReviseItem'` (which will evaluate to `TRUE` because `'ReviseItem'` is "truey") and then doing another *OR* with *its* result against `'EndItem'`, and so on.

What you should use instead is `IN`, like so:

```sql
jobtype IN( 'AddItem', 'ReviseItem', 'EndItem', 'SoldReport', ... )
```

This will evaluate to `TRUE` when the value of `jobtype` is equal to one of the values inside the parentheses.

Comment: thanks it wasnt showing any error that is why i thought its logically correct

Comment: yes that is what i said other way! "i thought but i was wrong "

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you don't want it to return certain rows you'll need a `WHERE` clause to exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Stored procedure, to get the time difference, and rerun the correct color in one go?

Found this sample on the web at http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#841:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PeriodLen; 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS NumLabel; 
DELIMITER go 
CREATE FUNCTION PeriodLen( dt1 datetime, dt2 datetime ) RETURNS CHAR(128) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE yy,m0,mm,d0,dd,hh,mi,ss,t1 BIGINT; 
  DECLARE dtmp DATETIME; 
  DECLARE t0 TIMESTAMP; 
  SET yy = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dt1,dt2); 
  SET m0 = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,dt1,dt2); 
  SET mm = m0 MOD 12; 
  SET dtmp = ADDDATE(dt1, interval m0 MONTH); 
  SET d0 = TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,dt1,dt2); 
  SET dd = TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,dtmp,dt2);  
  SET t0 = TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,d0,dt1); 
  SET t1 = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dt2,t0)); 
  SET hh = FLOOR(t1/3600); 
  SET mi = FLOOR(t1/60) - 60*hh; 
  SET ss = t1 - 3600*hh - 60*mi; 
  RETURN CONCAT( NumLabel(yy,'year'), NumLabel(mm,'month'),  
                 Numlabel(dd,'day'), NumLabel(hh,'hour'),  
                 NumLabel(mi,'min'), NumLabel(ss,'sec')  
               ); 
END; 
go 
CREATE FUNCTION NumLabel( ival int, clabel char(16) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(24) 
RETURN Concat( ival, ' ', clabel, If(ival=1,' ','s ') ); 
go 
DELIMITER ; 


SELECT PeriodLen( '2000-7-1 20:34:35', '2011-08-24 15:53:42' ); 
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
| PeriodLen( '2000-7-1 20:34:35', '2011-08-24 15:53:42' ) | 
+---------------------------------------------------------+ 
| 11 years 1 month 22 days 19 hours 19 mins 7 secs        | 
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Just change it, so that it returns the color, instead of the time lapse.

Call it like this:

```
SELECT PeriodLen( '2000-7-1 20:34:35', '2011-08-24 15:53:42' );
```

Comment: thanks for the info i vl try after trying it simply frm the prev solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,creationtime,NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

This works out `NOW() - creationtime` in hours so that you can compare to an integer (it is 2 hours you wanted, not 2 days, correct?).

```
SELECT jobid,
      creationtime,
      jobstatus, 
      jobtype,  
      store_id,
      IF( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,creationtime,NOW()) > 2) && jobstatus!='complete' 
          &&  jobtype IN('AddItem','ReviseItem','EndItem','SoldReport', 
                'ReviseFixedPriceItem','AddFixedPriceItem','EndFixedPriceItem'), 
          'red',
          IF( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,creationtime,NOW()) > 18) && jobstatus!='complete'
             && jobtype ='ActiveInventoryReport',
             'red',
             'white'
            )
        ) AS jobstatus_color
    FROM ebay.lms_jobs
    ORDER BY jobtype
```

Comment: SELECT jobid,
    creationtime,
    jobstatus, 
    jobtype,  
    store_id,
    IF( (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,creationtime,NOW()) > 2) && jobstatus NOT IN('complete','aborted') && jobtype IN('AddItem','ReviseItem','EndItem','SoldReport','ReviseFixedPriceItem','AddFixedPriceItem','EndFixedPriceItem'),'red',IF((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,creationtime,NOW()) > 18) && jobstatus NOT IN('complete','aborted') && jobtype ='ActiveInventoryReport','red','white')) AS jobstatus_color
  FROM ebay.lms_jobs
  ORDER BY jobtype

Comment: this is the query after updating but its showing results with jobstatus complete

Comment: Add `WHERE jobstatus != 'complete'`?